# Right way to set the OAuth Authorization header?

Tags: php, oauth, header

I want to set a request header for a url xyz.com
is it the right way to set it in php?

```
header('Authorization: AuthSub token="xxxxxx"');
header('location:https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRevokeToken');
```

I am trying to set the header for this URL for a call.But the Authorization: AuthSub header doesnt shows up in the request headers section of the FireFox NET panel.Which is used to show the requests.

Any idea about it?
Thanx.

I was using curl previously,But it didnt seemed to issue any request as i cant see it in the NET panel of FireFox.
Code is as follows:

```
$curl = curl_init(); 

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRevokeToken"); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);   
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: AuthSub token="1/xxx"'
                    )); 
    $result = curl_exec($curl);  
    curl_close($curl);            
    echo 'hererer'.$result;exit;
```

Comment: You can not "see" curl requests of your PHP script in the net panel of firebug in firefox. So it's okay nothing was displayed.

Comment: Yes Hakre,I got it now.But it doesnt even shows me anything in the print of curl_exec() it should reply with a HTTP 200 message they say that in the manual

Answer (score 1):

[`header`](http://php.net/header) sets response headers, not request headers. (If you were trying to send a HTTP request elsewhere, it would have no effect.)

Please also note what the manual says about `Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, ...`.

And turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL);` before using `header()` to see if that is the issue for you.

Answer (score 1):

Header names and values need to be separated by one colon plus a space, so the location "header" is just wrong, it should be:

```
header('Location: https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRevokeToken');
```

(It's common to write the case this way, too, but not a need)

Next to that the `header` function is setting response headers, not request headers. So you're basically using the wrong tool.

In PHP you can not set request headers, that's part of the client (e.g. browser), not the server. So `header` just looks wrong here. Which HTTP client are you using?

Comment: Yes Hakre,It is actually related to AuthSub of YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

A call, as in using CURL to request another page? The header() function applies only for web-browser<->server communications. It cannot affect any requests your server-side script does to other webservers. For that, you need to modify the particular method you're using, e.g. curl or streams.

For curl, see `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` here: http://php.net/curl_setopt

Comment: Hello Marc,I was trying to use the curl but it doesnt issues any request,I dont know why.I didnt saw ne request being generated in the NET panel of FireFoz.I will edit the code to put my curl code there.

Comment: curl operates on the server... a client-side network monitor will never see it, because that request will never even enter the client's network

Comment: I see Marc,But it doesnt gives me any output in the response variable that i have printed.The Manual say it should get back to me with a HTTP 200 message.Which i dont see in a print of curl_exec.