# php make post request with header

Tags: php, post, curl, header, request

Using php, i need to call a webservice, passing in specific data in the HTTP header, and specific data in the actual POST string.  However, when ever i access this page, the page attempts to download.  If I open the downloaded file, it contains only my two !'s.  From what I understand, a response should be sent back.

Am I correctly "sending" the headers to the url defined below, or should i be doing it differently?

Thanks!

```
<?php 
    header("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    header("Content-Length: ---");
    header("Authorization: Basic -------");

try{

    $xml = "------";

    $url = 'https://---.com/---/---?site_id=---&service_name=---';

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    echo "!" . $response . "!";

} catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r($e);
}

?>
```

Comment: `header("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` is telling the browser that your response has that encoding. Looks like that's the reason why it refuses to display it and offers a download instead. `header` is setting the response headers, not the request headers, compare with http://stackoverflow.com/q/7573251/367456

Comment: aha, that makes sense with what Marc B said as well. i have made some progress and now get a response back from the other side :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The PHP `header()` call will issue headers that affect the connection between the web server and YOUR browser. it does not in any way affect the connection the server is creating with curl.

By default, curl will automatically fill in the appropriate content-type headers when you tell it to do a POST, and is smart enough to change the content type if you're doing a file upload as well. To specify the login credentials, use `CURLOPT_USERPWD` (see http://php.net/curl_setopt for details).

Answer (score -1):

It looks like it's a https issue which might be solved through:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Cheers!

Comment: after Marc B got me in the right direction with USERPWD... i was able to get to the url and get a response... which was an error.  this post of yours, fixed that new error!!! thanks!

Comment: @adam: after I wrote the response I figured out what your main problem was, but Marc was faster. I'm glad it worked after-all.